# JQuery Returning Null .next()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a way to alert the contents of a p tag without a class, name or an id. It is a child of a tag named 'question' so I thought I could just next into it. There are 2 p tags under the parent tag, the one Im looking for is 2nd. When I run this it returns null. I can't figure out why because I'm new to JQuery, thanks for the help.

```js
alert($('#question').find('p').first().next().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td id="question">
  <p>First</p>
  <p>This is the one I want</p>
</td>
```

Comment: Also make sure your script is wrapped inside $(function(){//your code here});

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is fine. The problem is with your HTML. You probably forgot to wrap it inside a table and a tr:

```js
alert($('#question').find('p').first().next().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="question">
      <p>First</p>
      <p>This is the one I want</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your code from the question doesn't work since when `<td>` is without `<table>` and `<tr>` then it gets rendered like there was not `<td>`:

```
  <p>First</p>
  <p>This is the one I want</p>
```

[see here](https://jsfiddle.net/Keammoort/ggrkn0Lw/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that markup is invalid. You can't have `td` element by itself without `table` and `tr` elements. So what happens, is that browser fixes broken markup by removing orphan `td` tag.

It will work if you make HTML valid:

```js
alert($('#question').find('p').first().next().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="question">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>This is the one I want</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you check the code in the inspector you can see that as `table` and `tr` tags are not present then your `td` tag is not present either and the `$('#question')` returns null. Just add them.

```js
alert($('#question').find('p').first().next().text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="question">
      <p>First</p>
      <p>This is the one I want</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It was just a mock up version of the code. Does the JQuery work? It wasn't the actual website and it isn't my html code. The whole website was one huge table so it was very watered down.

Comment: This is a running sample you can test it trough the Run code snippet button. If you need something else please provide more HTML code.